# pandas Consolidate same values in the same row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

There are the following data:

```
  board_href_deals       items  test1
0            test2  {'x': 'a'}  test1
1            test2  {'x': 'b'}  test2
```

After grouping "board_href_deals", 
I would like to output the existing data in a list format as follows:

```
 board_href_deals                     items     test1
0            test2  [{'x': 'a'}, {'x': 'b'}]    ['test1', 'test2']
```

thank you

Comment: How working `df.groupby('board_href_deals').agg(list)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html), tested in `pandas 0.23.4`:

```
df = df.groupby('board_href_deals', as_index=False).agg(list)
print (df)
  board_href_deals                     items           test1
0            test2  [{'x': 'a'}, {'x': 'b'}]  [test1, test2]
```

Thank you @jpp for solution for oldier pandas:

```
df = df.groupby('board_href_deals').agg(lambda x: list(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, especially on older versions of Pandas, is to use `GroupBy` + `apply` on a sequence, then combine via `concat`.

Benchmarking on Python 3.60 / Pandas 0.19.2. This contrived example has a small number of groups; you should test with your data if efficiency is a concern.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['test2', 'test2', 'test4', 'test4'],
                   'B': [{'x': 'a'}, {'x': 'b'}, {'y': 'a'}, {'y': 'b'}],
                   'C': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']})

df = pd.concat([df]*10000)

def jpp(df):
    g = df.groupby('A')
    L = [g[col].apply(list) for col in ['B', 'C']]
    return pd.concat(L, axis=1).reset_index()

%timeit jpp(df)                                 # 11.3 ms per loop
%timeit df.groupby('A').agg(lambda x: list(x))  # 20.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Be carefull, there are only 4 big groups, so it is faster. I think in more groups your solution should be slowier.

Comment: @jezrael, Yep, as always user should test on their data. It *may* be better depending on ratio of # groups vs items per group.

Comment: I'll add a comment. We don't have enough data to make a judgement one way or the other. Best to show all solutions :)

Comment: sure, so if add solution for more groups it should really good ;)

Comment: @jezrael, Disagree, that's *not* necessary. Different solutions can cater for different edge cases. It's common practice on SO. It's also one reason we don't close down questions once they're answered!